# I have a problem with an eventhandler (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling

This code is from one class

```
 Button pagebtn = new Button();
 pagebtn.Text = "2";

 pagebtn.Click += 
        listTopicPerPage_Click(this, new btnEventArgs() { btnNumber = 2 });
```

I get an underline on the eventHandler method saying..

> *cannot immplicitly convert type 'void'
>   to 'System.EventHandler'.*

Why is that?

Code from a different class that i created:

```
class btnEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int btnNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the event parameters you should create a event field in your class, and rise it up on demand:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public event EventHandler<btnEventArgs> SampleEvent;

    public void DemoEvent(int val)
    {
        // Copy to a temporary variable to be thread-safe.
        EventHandler<btnEventArgs> temp = SampleEvent;
        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new btnEventArgs { btnNumber = val });
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
    }

    void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DemoEvent(2);
    }
}

class btnEventArgs : EventArgs 
{
    public int btnNumber { get; set; } 
}
```

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx)

Comment: I am not totally sure what u did there. But i guess, you want me to crea a new method..and do it in a long way..not sure it is necessary

Comment: You can't pass the parameters in the delegate assignment. So you must create your own method to bubble the event

Comment: Why does the method need a string val parameter, and what is SampleEvent?

Comment: Read the MSDN article, please :). What just a pseudo-code to show you how you should do the event assignment

Comment: But i have inbuilt event, btn.Click. Do i need to go all that way around, creating another custom eventhandler, then triggering it as well as soon as the orginal click event goes off?!?! (ps. no need to be thread safe, thanks)

Comment: ' pagebtn.Click += 
        listTopicPerPage_Click(this, new btnEventArgs() { btnNumber = 2 });' is trying to call 'listTopicPerPage_Click()' and store the return value in pagebtn.Click.  This is why you get the error.  the return value is void.  You need to store the function in the event handler, but you cannot specify what data gets passed to the event handler at this point in the code.

Comment: EventArgs lol= (EventArgs)new btnEventArgs() { btnNumber = i };
            pagebtn.Click += listTopicPerPage_Click(this,lol); That wouldnt work too.. But it does seem valid

Comment: It won't.  What I was trying to say is that you cannot pass it the data here.  btn.Click can only be given a method, not the values to pass to the method.  When the btn.Click event is raised is when the parameter data is given.  This is done by the framework when the button is clicked.  You have no control over that here.

Comment: VMAtm. was right, but I am not sure why, i couldnt cast before

Comment: Because `.Click` field is a delegate instance of type EventHandler, and you can't add the method parameters to it - only reference to a method. See the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx for more information about events and delegates

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
pagebtn.Click += new EventHandler(listTopicPerPage_Click);
```

Comment: But listTopicPerPage_Click() isn't implemented/defined. :D

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

```
pagebtn.Click += listTopicPerPage_Click;
```

Comment: this would not work because in this way btnNumber is not defined.

Comment: It's not defined in his example either but it doesn't mean it's not in the code. That's not really the issue at hand anyways. You could also argue that none of the code will work considering he doesn't have using statements for the appropriate namespaces.

Comment: This will cal the anonimous method, in which simply the btnNumber will be initialized. This closure is not the solution for this

Comment: still, number i am trying to pass isnt defined

Comment: You define EventArgs when you raise an event. Since you most likely can't raise the event (they can only be raised within the object) you will want to define btnNumber in a different way.

Comment: I did define it in a different way.. still got the same error. the answer isnt there

Comment: Ok so if you need btnNumber defined, how do you need to reference it?

Answer (score 0):

it's because your method signature of the listTopicPerPage_Click is something like

```
protected void listTopicPerPage_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
```

There are a couple of things you can do here,

You can update your method signature to use btnEventArgs instead of EventArgs

```
protected void listTopicPerPage_Click( object sender, btnEventArgs e )
```

or you can cast your new btnEventArgs to be EventArgs and then cast it back to btnEventArgs in the method body.

```
pagebtn.Click += 
    listTopicPerPage_Click(this, (EventArgs) new btnEventArgs() { btnNumber = 2 });

protected void listTopicPerPage_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{    
   btnEventArgs bea = (btnEventArgs) e;

   ...
}
```

Comment: none of the above problems solve the question i have already changed EventArgs to btnEventArgs in the eventhandler method

Comment: @Matrix001, if you have btnEventArgs in the eventhandler then you cast e to btnEventArgs to access btnNumber.

Comment: This will not compile: pagebtn.Click +=      listTopicPerPage_Click(this, (EventArgs) new btnEventArgs() { btnNumber = 2 });

Comment: pagebtn.Click += listTopicPerPage_Click(this, (EventArgs)new btnEventArgs() { btnNumber = i });  I did this, it still shows the underline with the same comment un

Comment: This also doesn't compile. You don't returning the delegate. pagebtn.Click += listTopicPerPage_Click(this, (EventArgs)new btnEventArgs() { btnNumber = i });